# Opening a form C++ from 2 different forms

Tags: forms, c++-cli

I have 3 forms:

- MainForm
- ManualForm
- AutomaticForm

I have a button MainForm-> ManualForm:

```
private: System::Void btnPowerOn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    ManualForm^ form = gcnew ManualForm();
    form->ShowDialog();
}
```

I also have a button for AutomaticForm -> ManualForm:

```
private: System::Void btnManual_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    this->Close();

    ManualForm^ manForm = gcnew ManualForm();
    manForm->ShowDialog();
}
```

but when I added this second button it says:
syntax error: identifier 'ManualForm'. (in the AutomaticForm.h)

In both MainForm and AutomaticForm I have the #include "ManualForm.h".

So how can I solve this to let my buttons do their job? (switching between forms)

Answer (score -1):

Ok it seems it is a problem with including each other.
I simple solved it by not closing eachother and keeping the previous Form open.

So for each button I just do the following:

```
private: System::Void btn_Automatic_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    //this->Close(); removed this line so I don't have to reopen it again
    AutomaticForm^ aForm = gcnew AutomaticForm();
    aForm->ShowDialog();
}
```

and when I want to go back to the manualForm, I just simply do this:

```
private: System::Void btn_Manual_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    this->Close();
}
```